# Mono - missing file gnome-sharp at the momment to compile the gnome sample application

Tags: mono, monodevelop, fedora10

Latter of to create a new sample solution in monodevelop.

Mono -> New Solution -> C# -> Examples -> Gnome 2.0 Project

I found the next errors at the momment to compile the  gnome sample application.

Building: test (Debug)

Construyendo solución test

Building: test (Debug)
Realizando compilación principal...
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings

/Projects/test/test/MyProgram.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gnome' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Construcción finalizada -- 2 errores, 0 advertencias

The gnome-sharp file, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f was not found or is invalid.

Construcción: 2 errors, 0 warnings

---

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

My environment is: Monodevelop 2.0 (Alpha 1), Linux Fedora 10

[root@internet sandovaledwin]# rpm -qa mono*
monodoc-2.2-2.fc10.i386
monodevelop-1.9-8.fc10.i386
mono-core-2.2-2.fc10.i386
mono-winforms-2.2-2.fc10.i386
mono-addins-0.3.1-3.fc10.3.i386
mono-data-2.2-2.fc10.i386
mono-web-2.2-2.fc10.i386
mono-nunit22-2.2.10-7.fc10.i386
mono-extras-2.2-2.fc10.i386
mono-basic-2.2-1.fc10.i386
mono-data-sqlite-2.2-2.fc10.i386

Answer (score 3):

you need to install the gnome-sharp package